# How to create a rule that checks an extra profile field created with the core profile module?

Tags: 7, users, rules

I have a Drupal 7 site with the [Honeypot](https://www.drupal.org/project/honeypot) module installed. Honeypot removes or prevents many spam registrations, but not all. I have extra fields added to the profile e.g. 'profile_field1'. I'd like to build a rule using the Rules modules that either deletes an account or prevents it from being created if the content of the 'profile_field1' doesn't match a certain regular expression.
I cannot find how to create a rule that can handle an extra profile field.
What I'd like to create:

```
'before saving a new user account'
if profile_field1 does not match RegExPattern
then prevent account from being created
```

I can find how to create a condition based on the 'regular' fields in the account (such as the name), but I cannot find how to test for the extra fields.

**Update 1**: the field 'profile_field1' is part of the Users profile, i.e. the Drupal Profile module is enabled. This module is part of D7 and similar in functionality to drupal.org/project/profile (for D8). It's found in [drupal]/modules/profile. Configuration settings are in admin/config/people/profile.

**Update 2**: I checked in the database. There is no table called 'profile_field1'. The info is in 'profile_field' which defines all fields and in profile_value, which contains all values.
So, e.g. profile_field1 would be fid=1 in table profile_field. Then user 5 (uid = 5) would have a record in profile_value with fid = 1, uid = 5, value = 'content of field'.

**Update 3**: With the suggestions in the answer I was able to migrate the information from the old Profile to the Profile2 fields. Write up is here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2916659

**Update 4**: At least I can create a Rules rule now. Just wondering if this is the best:

```
{ "rules_prevent_spam_registration" : {
    "LABEL" : "Prevent spam registration",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "user_presave" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "entity_has_field" : {
          "entity" : [ "account-unchanged:profile-personal" ],
          "field" : "field_profile_field1"
        }
      },
      { "AND" : [
          { "text_matches" : {
              "text" : [ "account-unchanged:field-profile-field1" ],
              "match" : "<regexPattern>",
              "operation" : "regex"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [ { "entity_delete" : { "data" : [ "account-unchanged" ] } } ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Since your question is about D7, the profile module cannot be https://www.drupal.org/project/profile ... which only exists for D8. Can you edit your question again, to include the URL of "your" profile module? PS: I do not like the "chat"-interface on drupal.SE, sorry.

Comment: chat: no problem. Question updated

Comment: Please review the edit I applied to the title of your question (to make it more accurate). If you don't like it, just perform a rollback. Also check my updated answer ... something like "as good as it gets"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the limited info provided in your question, the best bet is that you cannot test for that extra field because you forgot to add a Rules Condition like "entity has field" (related to your `profile_field1` field). So add that Rules Condition first (as your very first Rules Condition), and then try again.

For a video tutorial that illustrates the importance of this `Entity has field` condition, refer to [Data types and data selection](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/data-types-and-data-selection), especially what is shown between about 13:30 and 17:30 in it.

**Update**:

As per your updates to your question, I now understand that you're using the deprecated (core) `profile` module. This is a quote from its .info file:

> ; The Profile module is deprecated, and included in Drupal 7 for legacy
>
> ; purposes only. By default, the module will be hidden from the UI unless you
>
> ; are upgrading a site that uses the Profile module to extend user profiles.

Because of that, I doubt that there is a way to use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module to check "*if the content of the 'profile_field1' doesn't match a certain regular expression*" (as in your question). Mostly because the Rules Condition like "entity has field" (=  typical prereq to configure these kinds of Rules Conditions) will not have any effect for such `profile_field1`-field. Maybe not the answer you would want to hear/read, but I'm afraid it explains that what you're asking for cannot be done with Rules.

**Plan-b**:

Give it some thought to consider switching to the [Profile 2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) module. Quote from its project page:

> Designed to be the successor of the core profile module, which is [deprecated](https://www.drupal.org/node/874026) for Drupal 7. In contrast to the deprecated module this module provides a new, fieldable 'profile' entity - leverage the power of fields!
>
> **Features**
>
> ... Thanks to the foundational [entity API](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity) the module integrates well with Rules ...

If you do, pretty sure my original answer (= add a Rules Condition like "entity has field") will turn out to be the solution for what you try to achieve.

Comment: Well, I tried that but there is no way to select the field 'profile_field1'. If I use 'entity has field' and I choose either 'account' or 'account-unchanged' I can select all kinds of fields that are part of my content types, but I cannot select 'profile_field1'. And since it's a drop down list, I cannot add it manually

Comment: @hepabolu please EDIT your question to include an EXPORT of the rule you have so far. It may help to further improve my answer also.

Comment: I'd love to but so far I have nothing, other than the event

Comment: that is what I feared ... next attempt: where does that field come from, how is it configured, some module that created it?

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me. It's added in admin/config/people/profile. It's configured as a text field, private field, but visible at user registration, user must enter a value. I think it's standard Drupal.

Comment: @hepabolu D7 core does not have a path like admin/config/people/profile , so which module did you enable that created that path in your case? I think I can ***guess*** your answer, but I want you to clarify that as part of your question, so that I don't have to guess about that in my updated answer later on ...

Comment: It's the Drupal Profile module, i.e. part of Drupal. Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah, never realised it was deprecated. I must have enabled it way back when it was a Drupal 6 site. I'm going to check out the Profile 2 module. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, I was off to figure out if I could use it.